# Use erb partials, in Rails, to append the DOM using JavaScript - not hitting controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a form that has a variable number of line items, each having the same inputs and icons and lots of other elements. I have a `_line_item.html.erb` partial that gets used in a loop in the view to show existing line items.

I also have a button, at the bottom, that when clicked will add a new, blank line item to the page. Doing so, however, doesn't hit the controller and happens completely client side. Currently, I just have a variable in my javascript that is a big string equal to the same HTML in the partial. I have to edit and maintain the erb partial and the javascript string separately, though.

This is all kind of ugly, and not at all DRY, so I was wondering - is there any way to leverage the HTML present in the erb partial for appending new line items, WITHOUT having to hit the controller first? Or, is there a better client-side way of handling appending reusable blocks of HTML?

Also, cloning is not an option since at some point the user could remove all their line items. I guess I could leave a hidden one in the DOM somewhere, rendered via the erb partial, but that also feels not great.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it something like:

- add a new form at the end of your `line_item` list (rendered when you are rending the list) that is hidden via `display: none` in your css
- when you click the `add` button (or whatever it's called), show the new form (and probably hide the `add` button). For the form, I like to use a `slideDown()` function
- when the user fills in the form and clicks `submit` (or however you submit the form), then do your `create` ajax call to the server. In your controller, render `_line_item.html.erb`
- `.on 'ajax:success'`, append the `line_item` html to your list (maybe sorting, if that floats your boat), re-hide your new form (similar to above, I use `slideUp()`), and re-show your `add` button.

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing is somewhat equivalent to what most implementations do.

[Some implementations](https://github.com/ncri/nested_form_fields) store the HTML in a `<script type="text/html">` like tag, which may be a bit less painful for the updating of templates than maintaining a gigantic HTML string.